# Yaml list and object difference, and their usage

Tags: types, yaml

Sorry, a basic type question. Just started with YAML..
what is the difference between - list: and object:?

to https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-validator, both the YAML are validate. Even when all the "-" is removed.
Thanks!

```
---

- name: Add Keys to Hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Install Key
    authorized_key:
      user: root
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

---

```
---
- name: Add Keys to Hosts
  hosts: all
- tasks:
  - name: Install Key
    authorized_key:
      user: root
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    name2: Install Key
    authorized_keys:
        - name: test
        - name: Apple
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks costaparas!
My question isn’t about ansible, more about YAML. Apologize for my grammar. And I’m not a developer.
Just started with Ansible and trying to get the ssh key of the control node into some hosts, but I cheated... used `for i in {200..250}; do ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.101.$i >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts ; done` before running that Ansible playbook. I’m aware this ad hoc one line just append, it missed the codes to check & update `known_hosts`, logging and summarize the result which I should be able to easily achieve via Ansible.. if I know how to use Ansible.

tested via `ansible all -m command -a "df -h"`

Sorry about the second example, I knew it don't work in Ansible.. it was just to communicate the syntax.

With Ansible out of the way, back to YAML question.

After testing, my understanding of ‘list’ is a grouping of entries/items (entry being a key /value pairs or simple value). Or a single item in a ‘list’. Grouping can also be achieved via nesting of key:value pair.

When to use ‘list’ will depend on the application/software which will parse the content. Example; *tasks* key name in ansible and *containers* Kubernetes need to contain ‘list’. What follow those ‘keyname:’ in the next line must be a “-“.

The difference (in YAML at least); a "list" can have item with the same key name. And likely there is an order or positional of items in a "list". Duplicate key names are not allowed for key:value pair not in a "list". A “list” is indexed order of items which can repeat, while key:value pair at the same level (of indentation) are like files in a folder, no duplicated filename. To create a "list" using nested key:value pair is possible, but troublesome to create folder1, folder2, etc.. to separate same filename file, and not easy to insert another item inbetween. Likely "list" have auto positional indexing build in.

Next; Key:value can contain other key:value or "list", same for "list". But **can’t** have in the same level "key:value" and "list" mixed. Example; creating key1 with 2 key:value and 1 "list" with 2 items (key4 and [key5,key6]).

```
Key1: 
   key2: Covid
   key3: CFR
-  key4: systemctl
-  key5: motd
   key6: dig
```

Another is;

```
Key1:     
  - key1: XX     
    key2: XX
    key3: XX
  - key1: xx      # OK, same key name
    key2: xx    
    key2: XX      # Not OK!, same as key name above
```

I used https://onlineyamltools.com/validate-yaml to test, but https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator provided difference result for duplicated keyname. I assumed the more restrictive one is 'more' correct.

Not sure I missed any point or/and there is misunderstanding. This likely is crystal clear to developer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since its pretty clear you're writing an Ansible [playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/) here, the version you actually want is the first version. The second version is invalid from Ansible's perspective (even though its valid YAML syntax).

Now with that out of the way, I'll explain how this YAML syntax works.

Let's break down the distinction by referring to the [YAML language specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html).

> [Chapter 1
> Introduction](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Introduction):
>
> ---
>
> There are myriad flavors of data structures, but they can all be adequately
> represented with three basic primitives: mappings
> (hashes/dictionaries), sequences (arrays/lists) and scalars
> (strings/numbers).
>
> [3.2.1.1. Nodes](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044)
>
> ---
>
> A YAML node represents a single native data structure. Such nodes have
> content of one of three kinds: scalar, sequence, or mapping.

So, in essence, there are three core structures in YAML:

- Scalars, the most primitive unit
- Sequences, which are essentially lists or arrays
- Mappings, which are key-value pairs

In YAML, when you use `-`, then you are saying whatever comes next is part of a *sequence* (a list). When you use a `:` then what you're saying is the thing on the left is a "key" and the thing on the right is a "value" (and together, they form a "key-value pair").

But things are more complex than this, since of course, you can nest these structures.

Let's take a simple example:

```
---
my_shopping_list:
  - apples
  - eggs
  - oranges
  
friends_shopping_list:
  - chocolate
  - beer
  - bacon
```

In this example, we have a mapping - with two keys (`my_shopping_list` and `friends_shopping_list`) and each has a corresponding value. In this case, the values are sequences (lists) -- *the shopping lists of two friends*.

In YAML, you can also write sequences using the more common array notation from many programming languages. So the following is equivalent to the above:

```
---
my_shopping_list:
  [apples, eggs, oranges]
  
friends_shopping_list:
  [chocolate, beer, bacon]
```

Things can go the other way, too -- we can have a sequence composed of mappings. In fact, that's exactly what your playbook example is. Let's delve deeper into it.

```
---
- name: Add Keys to Hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: Install Key
    authorized_key:
      user: root
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

In Ansible, playbooks consist of a *sequence* of plays. In your example, there is **one** play (the whole thing you see here constitutes a single play).

Within a play, we have a mapping (key-value pairs). In this example, these are:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name | "Add Keys to Hosts" (a scalar) |
| hosts | "all" (a scalar) |
| tasks | a YAML sequence |

In Ansible, a play can have one or more tasks (hence the use of a sequence!). In this case, there's only **one** task. The task itself is a mapping, namely:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| name | "Install Key" (a scalar) |
| authorized_key (name of Ansible module to use) | a YAML mapping |

So I hope you can see where this is going. There's quite a bit of nesting happening -- `authorized_key` is a mapping, and has 3 key-value pairs. (In Ansible `authorized_key` is one of the [standard modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/authorized_key_module.html)).

Finally, let's take a quick look at your second example:

```
---
- name: Add Keys to Hosts
  hosts: all
- tasks:
  - name: Install Key
    authorized_key:
      user: root
      state: present
      key: "{{ lookup('file', '/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
    name2: Install Key
    authorized_keys:
        - name: test
        - name: Apple
```

This of course is valid *YAML*, but as a playbook makes no sense. Remember, a playbook is a sequence of plays and each play is a mapping, where one of the keys (`tasks`) is a sequence of tasks. This second example presents itself as a sequence where the first element is a mapping and the second is a sequence. In Ansible, the `tasks` are part of the play; whereas in this snippet, they are separate elements of a sequence. Hence, Ansible wouldn't treat this as a valid playbook.

Comment: Thanks costaparas! Please get me a little time to reply.. preparing and testing.

Comment: costaparas, thanks again and hope this 2021 will be better for everyone. I responded awhile back to the question. Basically is my lack of programming experience..

Comment: What exactly is your question/concern?

Comment: The question which bugged me was YAML “list” and “object”, since object can also be used to hold a group of data, why not just use object. Anyway, I think I got it now. Thanks!!!